# Why it seems that the function I defined can't run

Tags: c, function

When run, I cannot input anything and the program just end and return nothing, though in my code I want to input and output something. And then I tried to debug, I set a lot of key points in the function that I defined, but it directly goes to the end of the code. It seems that the function I defined can't be run. I am confused about that. Could you tell me what was wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void day_of_year();
int main() {

    day_of_year;
    return 0;
}
void day_of_year()

{
    int year; int month; int day;

    scanf_s("%d %d %d", &year, &month, &day);
    int day_tab[2][13] = {

    {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},

    {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31} };

    int flag, j;

    flag = (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 100 != 0) && (year % 4) == 0);

    for (j = 1; j < month; j++)  day += day_tab[flag][j];
    printf("%d", day);
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function as `day_of_year()`. Else, see link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call the function, your statement should read `day_of_year();`, with the parentheses.

Without the parentheses, `day_of_year;` is an expression that evaluates the address of the function, then doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **call** it by adding a set of parenthesis. Otherwise it's just an unused expression.

```
int main() {

    day_of_year();
    return 0;
}
```